# integrating Dropzone with self-sufficient form PHP

Tags: javascript, php, forms, file-upload, dropzone.js

Hello have an issue `url` option doesn't work in dropzone.
dropzone works well but have an issue with uploading to the folder for sending into email.

Can help me? how I can send images from dropzone into PHP file for future processing and move them into a certain folder?
[image]

Here is my code of `form`

```
  <form action="send.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['token'] ?? '' ?>">
            <div class="rating_wrapper">
                <?php 
                    for ($i=1; $i <=6 ; $i++) { 
                        ?>
                        <div class=" rating_box">
                            <img src="img/human_grey.png">
                                <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating-<?= $i ?>" value="<?= $i ?>">
                                <label for="rating-<?= $i ?>" class="rating-input__box">
                                    <div class="rating-checked"></div>
                                    <div class="rating_number">
                                        <?= $i ?>
                                    </div>
                                </label>
                        </div>
                <?php                        
                    }
                    for ($i=7; $i <=8 ; $i++) {
                        ?>
                        <div class=" rating_box">
                            <img src="img/human_white.svg">
                            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating-<?= $i ?>" value="<?= $i ?>">
                            <label for="rating-<?= $i ?>" class="rating-input__box">
                                <div class="rating-checked"></div>
                                <div class="rating_number">
                                    <?= $i ?>
                                </div>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                <?php
                    }
                    for ($i=9; $i <=10 ; $i++) {
                        ?>
                        <div class=" rating_box">
                            <img src="img/human_green.svg">
                            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating-<?= $i ?>" value="<?= $i ?>">
                            <label for="rating-<?= $i ?>" class="rating-input__box">
                                <div class="rating-checked"></div>
                                <div class="rating_number">
                                    <?= $i ?>
                                </div>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                <?php
                    }
                    ?>
            </div>
            <div class="measurement">
                <div class="measurement_low">Not at all likely</div>
                <div class="measurement_arrow"></div>
                <div class="measurement_hight">Extremely likely</div>
            </div>

            <h3>please explain <span class="accent">why you gave this score </span></h3>
            <div class="o-constrained">
                <div  class="c-dropzone">
                    <textarea class="c-dropzone__textarea" name="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                <!--begin::Input group-->
                    <div class="dropzone" id="kt_dropzonejs_example_1">
                        <!--begin::Message-->
                        <div class="dz-message needsclick">
                            <!--begin::Icon-->
                            <i class="bi bi-file-earmark-arrow-up text-primary fs-3x"></i>
                            <!--end::Icon-->
                            <!--begin::Info-->
                            <div class="ms-4">
                                <div id="upload-label" >
                                    <img class="upload-icon" src="img/icons8.png">
                                </div>
                                <!--end::Info-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--end::Dropzone-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-fields">
                <input  type="textarea" 
                        placeholder="your name"
                        name="sname"
                >
                <input  type="tel" id="phone" name="phone"
                        placeholder="your phone number"
                        required>
                <input  type="email" id="email"
                        placeholder="your email"
                        name="email"
                      
                        size="30"
                        required>
            </div>
            <div class="submit-area">
                <div class="contact-me">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="contact-me" id="contact-me">
                    <label for="contact-me">You may contact me for more details</label>
                </div>
                <div class="policy">
                    By giving us feedback you agree that Eumar can use your feedback to improve our products and services. Privacy statement
                    <input type="submit" value="submit">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

My `dropzone script`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#kt_dropzonejs_example_1", {
    url: "upload.php", // Set the url for your upload script location
    url: "upload.php", // Set the url for your upload script location
    paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
    maxFiles: 10,
    
    clickable: "#upload-label",
    maxFilesize: 10, // MB
    addRemoveLinks: true,
      acceptedFiles: "image/*",
    accept: function(file, done) {
        if (file.name == "wow.jpg") {
            done("Naha, you don't.");
        } else {
            console.log('success');
            done();
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

My `upload.php` file

```
$folder_name = 'upload/'.$_SESSION['token'].'/';
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    if (!mkdir($folder_name, 0777, true)) {
        die('Failed to create directories...');
    }
    $temp_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $location = $folder_name . $_FILES['file']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($temp_file, $location);
}
if (isset($_POST["name"])) {
    $filename = $folder_name.$_POST["name"];
    unlink($filename);
}
```